# C# Windows service executable file gets deleted

Tags: windows, service

I have created a Windows service and deployed it to a remote server.
I installed the service using `sc.exe` and the result was SUCCESS. The service ran for a couple of days then it crashed and I couldn't find it anymore in the "Services" list and the executable file was gone.
I have checked the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ServiceName\ImagePath` and it properly points to where the .exe file should have been.
Any idea how to debug this, or why the service was uninstalled?

Comment: Did you have Windows Explorer open when `sc.exe` was run? Did you see the file appear and then disappear? Did you `dir /s` to check whether the file might be somewhere else on the file system?

Comment: Could it be AV?

Comment: After the deploy, the file was there. After the failed start, it was gone. There is no AV running on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your uninstaller removes the registry entry, so you can exclude that. That means the service was not uninstalled, bu instead explicitly deleted.

By whom, when or why is not something you can typically retrieve. File auditing on NTFS is rarely enabled. But I'm pretty sure about the *who*. Files don't disappear spontaneously. And again assuming a good design, your service will be running under a user account with low permissions, so it can't delete itself. (There's also the added protection that a running EXE can't remove itself because the EXE is locked by the OS while running).